# Getting mysql Issue when pushing in docker from local machine (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

### I perform following steps to complete my tasks

step-1 : sudo docker docker-compose \
                 -f ./docker/wordpress.yml \
                 -f ./docker/puppeteer.yml \
                  run --rm \
                  --name poster-wordpress-test \ poster /bin/bash

---

### Project are configure in Wordpress and Mysql

After fire this Command i getting this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaQU6.png)

---

-> I have already install MySQL 5.7.28 in docker(version 18.06.3-ce),docker compose(version 1.21.0, build 5920eb0)